# php getting values from session

Tags: php, session

Hey guys I have a quick question I have a session and when I do a print_r of the session this is what I get...

```
Array ( [items] => a:1:{s:2:"1_";a:5:{s:2:"id";s:1:"1";s:4:"name";s:9:"Product 3";s:5:"price";s:5:"20.00";s:6:"option";N;s:3:"qty";N;}} )
```

I am trying to echo out the price and the name (price = 20.00, name = Product 3)

I've tried..

```
<?php echo $_SESSION['price']; ?>
```

and

```
<?php echo $_SESSION['items']['price']; ?>
```

nothing works...any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "nothing works"?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php

Comment: when I echo $_SESSION['items']['name'] i get 'a' when it should be 'Product 3'

Comment: Who is assigning values to session ? why dont you set session properly!!

Comment: @zod Would you please explain the problem with assigning values to `$_SESSION`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The contents of `$_SESSION['items']` seems to be [serialized](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php). Try

```
$items = unserialize($_SESSION['items']);

echo $items['1_']['price'];

var_dump($items);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php

Comment: It looks like it might have to be `echo $items['1_']['price']` after unserializing.

Comment: I bow before your parsing eyes - and changed my answer accordingly. ;-)

Comment: Great. So now your answer's just like mine was 5 minutes earlier ;)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the data is being serialized somehow. You could unserialize the data like this

```
$items = unserialize($_SESSION['items']);
```

however any changes you make to the items array will have to be updated to the session to be properly handled by whatever the script is doing with the data later with

```
$_SESSION['items'] = serialize($items);
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your serialized data, it appears you have to:

```
$items = unserialize($_SESSION['items']);

$items ['1_']['price'];
```

Not sure why there's a `1_` but it's in there.

Comment: Awesome, just what I was looking for :)

Comment: Glad to help. Remember to checkmark this answer (in the upper left).

Answer (score 0):

you have to define it first use session start and then you can use something along the lines of this sort of code below

```
     $data = mysql_query("select * FROM tablename where id = $id ") 
     or die(mysql_error()); 
     echo "<table border cellpadding=3>"; 
     while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 

and then you can echo the row you wish to by using $info example below

 echo "<th>User:</th> <td>".$info['user_name'] . "</td> ";
```